# Determine a function that satisfies the differential equation $f''(x) = -4y$?

Tags: calculus

How would I come to this solution? Is it a matter of working backwards?

$f'(x)= -y^4 + 3$?

Comment: So, what is $y$? Try using some $LaTeX$, also...

Comment: @LuizCordeiro what is LAT ex?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro LaTex?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro A tip: Type \latex when you want to get $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Usually, textbooks have a specific way of tackling differential equations of the form $ay'' + by' + cy = 0$. Have you tried working through the method given? If so, where did you get stuck? It is possible to explain it from scratch, but it's much easier to start from what you already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant:

$$y''(x) = -4y(x)$$

The solution for these type of equations is known to be a linear combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions. So, if you assume the solution is:
$$y(x) = A\sin(ax)+B\cos(bx)$$
Substitution will lead to $b= a = 2$, since:
$$y''(x) = -A a^2 \sin(ax) -B b^2 \cos(bx) = -4\left(A \sin(ax) + B \cos(bx)\right)$$
$$\to\quad a^2=b^2=4$$

As to how you could have figured it out without "guessing" you could use a power series expansion to show this.

Comment: whoa how did you its a linear combination of sin and cos? and how do you know you need to substitute b for 2?

Comment: and then how do we solve for a? what do we make f(x) equal?

Comment: @Jessica - is this clearer?

Comment: kind of but why exactly does b^2 = 4?